# How to change the way applications retrieve certificates from the certificate store on windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate-store

I was tasked with developing a way to change how applications retrieve certificates.

To be more precise: provide alternative ways for browsers to retrieve certificates to be used as client certificates on SLL connections other than having them read from the certificate store.

I found the Crypto tools on the windows API and the tools it provide to allow applications to read the certificate store. My current guess is that would have to involve changing the system's DLLs and there is no streamlined way of achieving my goal.

Comment: You are correct. You would have to change the operating system. Strange task.

Comment: A different company already did it. I was tasked with replicating whatever they did.